# What table structure would best fit this scenario?

Tags: mysql, structure

I am developing an evaluation system for different programs that needs a lot of flexibility. Each program will have different things to track, so I need to store what data points they want to track, and the corresponding data for the person being evaluated on the particular data point. I am guessing several tables are appropriate. Here is a general outline:

```
Table: accounts
- unique ID assigned to each account. We'll call this 'aid'

Table: users
- each user with unique ID.

Table: evaluation
- each program will enter in the metrics they want to track into this table (i.e attendance)
- column 'aid' will correspond to 'aid' in account table

Table: evaluation_data
- data (i.e attendance) entered into this database
- column 'aid' will correspond to 'aid' in account table
- column 'uid' will correspond to 'uid' in user table
```

The input form for evaluation_data will be generated from what's in the evaluation table.

This is the only logical way I can think of doing this. Some of these tables will be growing quite large over time. Is this the most optimal way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little confused about how accounts, users and programs all relate to each other and whether or not account and program are the same thing and that you used the terms interchangeably. I'm going to use different terms which are just easier for me to understand.

Say you have a website that allows freelancers to keep track of different projects and they can create their own data to track. (Hope you see the similarity)

Tables...

**freelancers**

```
id    title     etc
```

**projects**

```
id    freelancer_id    title    description    etc
```

**data_options**

```
id    freelancer_id    title
```

You can even add other columns like data_type and give options like URL, email, text, date, etc which can be used for validation or to help format the input form.

example data:

```
1    5    Status
2    5    Budget
3    5    Customer
4    99   Job Type
5    99   Deadline
6    102  Price
7    102  Status
8    102  Due By
```

This display 3 different freelancers tracking data, freelancers with the id's 5, 99, and 102. Deadline and Due By are essentially the same but freelancers can call these whatever they want.

**data_values**

```
id    project_id    option_id    option_value
```

a column freelancer_id as you would be able to to a join and get the freelancer_id from either the project_id or the option_id

example data:

```
1000     1      2     $250
1001     1      1     Completed
1002     1      3     Martha Hayes
```

This is only showing information freelancer with the id 5 has input because option_id's 1-3 belong to that user.

Comment: This is called EAV (for Entity-Attribute-Value).  If you need this kind of flexibility, it might help.  The biggest issues with it are (1) a record is now a bunch of rows rather than one, and (2) the database can't really enforce much in the way of constraints on the data.  Oh, and (3) indexing by value becomes a lot less useful.